# Oracle DB Query search using IN operator for 200 000+ search strings

Tags: database, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a user uploading a csv having 200k rows of IPs. I have to verify if the uploaded IPs already exists in database. What will be the optimized way to query the database?

I am using hibernate to connect to the Oracle DB and I am aware that IN query operator accepts limited values (1000). So to fetch 200k values it will execute 200 queries, which is time consuming and not an optimized way.

What is the best way to query the database?

Comment: Upload data to a separate (temporary?) table and do a JOIN or WHERE id IN query. Create an index On `id` in the opposite table.

Comment: Use a single MERGE statement from the temporary table proposed by krokodilko to the permanent table using IP as the filter/join.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect many collisions (uploaded IPs already in the database), I'd go for the staging table approach krokodilko and pmdba mentioned. Usually, I even compute a delta between existing and uploaded data, and log the numbers (120.000 ips already known, 25.000 new ips) to have some statistics.

On the other hand, if you don't expect collisions, and just want to protect your data from duplications, I'd use the error logging approach:

```
CREATE TABLE t (ip VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pkt PRIMARY KEY);

EXEC DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG(dml_table_name => 't');
```

Now you have your table `t` and an error log table `err$_t` which you can use to catch the offending rows:

```
INSERT INTO t (ip) VALUES ('127.0.0.1') LOG ERRORS;
1 row inserted.

INSERT INTO t (ip) VALUES ('127.0.0.1') LOG ERRORS;
0 rows inserted.
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SO.PKT) violated

SELECT ip, ora_err_mesg$ FROM err$_t;
IP          ORA_ERR_MESG$
127.0.0.1   ORA-00001: unique constraint (SO.PKT) violated
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however in my case there could be many collisions.